# Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am learning how to use Ionic by doing a test application but I have had this problem for two days. I have looked for possible solutions but none has worked for me.

The problem arises when I want to test my application on my android phone.
When using this command `ionic cordova run android` and gives me the following error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

I'm not sure what's wrong. My application it's very simple it's based on Ionic's template `ionic start myApp tabs` and I'm using **Ionic native plugin Geolocation**.

I've running `ionic info` and returns this

```
cli packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

I also checked the official Cordova's doc for [Android development](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) and my paths for Java and Android are OK.

Also with `ionic cordova requirements` everything looks to be OK.

```
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-23
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Faced the same issue, In my case the Android Target was ***platforms;android-19***. Installing ***platforms;android-25*** solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way i solved this problem is as below:

1)  npm uninstall cordova ionic

2) npm install -g cordova@7.0.0 ionic@3.19.0

3) cordova platform rm android

4) cordova platform add android

Answer (score 1):

This is due to compat plugin. 
Remove that plugin if you have older version (less than **1.2.0**) and set **cordova-android@6.3.0**

> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0
>
> cordova platform rm android
>
> ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0

Working at my case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside android folder under platforms folder there is a file called project.properties
Try replacing + with 27.1.0 in below lines

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+
```

Also do the same thing in build.gradle file

```
"com.android.support:support-v4:+"
"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
```

Answer (score 0):

For us, we just had to downgrade version of android

```
cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```