# IONIC 3: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

This error comes when execute "ionic cordova build android". Searched for a long time but no luck. Anyone can help?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 18s
(node:9516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`
```

Comment: try `cordova build android --verbose`

Comment: tried but no luck.

Comment: Can you add the full build log? It should have some errors from AAPT.

Answer (score 18):

I know it's a very late answer, incase someone still facing this issues in 2019.

It's caused due to gradle, add this gradle support plugin and it should be fine:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release
```

Comment: I tried different solutions but it worked for me. Thank you @mike

Comment: Solved my issue (November 17, 2019)

Comment: It's working (10-12-2020), I'm compiling my Ionic 2 project. on Ionic 5.

Comment: Works like gem on ionic 3 as well. Solved my issue on 27 October 2020

Answer (score 12):

run into the same error.
found this solution to fix it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49172982/7655348

Replace 
`com.android.support:support-v4:+` with `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0` in **project.properties** file under ***platform/android folder***

Comment: This fixed my issue, I had multiple entries for 'com.android.support:support' in project.properties with mixed values. (Probably from different plugins) Setting them all to the most specific seemed to fix the error (24.1.1+ for me)

Answer (score 2):

Also this solution worked for me:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/failed-build-for-android-execution-failed-for-task-app-processdebugresources/124551/3

Go to platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml and add:

```
<string name="fb_app_id">YOUR_FB_APP_ID</string>
<string name="fb_app_name">YOUR_FB_APP_NAME</string>
```

Then I had to did `cordova clean` and `ionic cordova build android`

Answer (score 1):

in the project folder try:

```
cordova clean
ionic cordova build <platform_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719314/execution-failed-for-task-cordovalibprocessdebugresources-com-android-ide/50678024#50678024)

This is due to compat plugin. 
Remove that plugin if you have older version (less than 1.2.0) and set **cordova-android@6.3.0**

> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0
>
> cordova platform rm android
>
> ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0

Working at my case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a android support problem. so first find out which android support library installed in your android sdk.

in my sdk com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+ so i replaced the code in project.properites file

cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+

Answer (score 0):

I just solve this issue by removing this line of code `cordova.system.library.15=com.android.support:support-v4:+`  , and the path to the file is `platforms/android/project.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Visit project.properties in your Ionic project...that is platform/android/project.properties

and replace like below

## Project target.

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/multipurposetheme- 
ignorelinterrors.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/multipurposetheme- 
androidtarget.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurred after i uninstall the Firebase plugin.

I tried alot of things but the simplest solution that i found was start a new project and replace the **src** folder with the new contents.