# Ionic 4 android platform build failed

Tags: ionic4

Im trying to run my app on device but its showing error of

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
```

This error is showing when im using firebase native plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be read this Documentation no longer need ionic plugin.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Install npm page and use this without plugin install.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548906/10585097

Solution mentioned :Replace com.android.support:support-v4:+ with com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 in project.properties file under platform/android folder